# логгирование gunicorn+flask+docker

Tags: python, python-3.x, веб-сервер, flask, gunicorn

Пытаюсь найти внятную информацию по поводу того, как логгировать rest api, написанное с помощью flask, в gunicorn.
Поднимаю flask на своей машине - в проекте заводится лог файл, в него сыпятся подробные логи
запускаю gunicorn - ничего никуда не сыпется

Хочу спросить - как правильно оформлять, запускать логи работы приложения с gunicorn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте этот вариант:

https://medium.com/@trstringer/logging-flask-and-gunicorn-the-manageable-way-2e6f0b8beb2f

или если нужно видеть в консоли запросы добавьте в gunicorn:

```
--log-level=debug
```